# How to make a div href to an image for slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm trying to make my slideshow's text divs refer it into an active background as a link but I can't seem to get it done.

What I am trying to get is everytime it loads the first text block has to have a background representing it as active and when you click the text on the text block it will become active and access to the content by clicking on the Headings (h1s).

I'll appreciate your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/EDc8M/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="sShow">
        <div id="sShowGallery">
            <ul>
                <li id="sld1"><a href="#article1"><img src="resource/images/sShow/img_news1.png" alt="img1" width="510" height="240"></a></li>
                <li id="sld2"><a href="#article2"><img src="resource/images/sShow/img_news2.jpg" alt="img2" width="510" height="240"></a></li>
                <li id="sld3"><a href="#article3"><img src="resource/images/sShow/img_news1.png" alt="img3" width="510" height="240"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="sShow_nav">
            <div class="sShow_bg">
                <a href="#article1"><h1>30 Characters max title 1</h1></a>
                <a href="#sld1"><p>Donec nisi velit, posuere sit amet bibendum at, hendrent rhoncus nunc. Aenean leo purus.</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="sShow_bg">
                <a href="#article2"><h1>30 Characters max title 2</h1></a>
                <a href="#sld2"><p>Donec nisi velit, posuere sit amet bibendum at, hendrent rhoncus nunc. Aenean leo purus.</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="sShow_bg">
                <a href="#article3"><h1>30 Characters max title 3</h1></a>
                <a href="#sld3"><p>Donec nisi velit, posuere sit amet bibendum at, hendrent rhoncus nunc. Aenean leo purus.</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sShowGallery").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $(".sShow_bg").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".sShow_bg a[href=#sld1]").addClass("ss_active");

    $("#sShow_nav").localScroll({
        target:'#sShowGallery', axis: 'x'
    });

    $(".sShow_bg a").click(function(){
        $(".sShow_bg a").removeClass("ss_active");
        $(this).addClass("ss_active");
    });
});
```

Comment: do you NOT want the paragraphs to show by default? i'm trying to figure out why you're stating that you want to require two separate actions to move the slide - *"access to the content by clicking on the Headings"* ... *"when you click the text on the text block it will become active"*

Comment: What I mean is that the Headings `"<h1>30 Characters max title 1</h1>"` would be the link and send you to the article and when you click on the Paragraph (block of text) would do the `.ss_active` on the slideshow. It will do 2 functions Heading link to the article and the Paragraph be the selector for the slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use two `anchors` in your `div` elements.

**html**

```
<div class="sShow_bg">
    <a href="#sld1"><h1>This is a title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet</p></a>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.sShow_bg a {
    display: block;
    /* other code here */
}
.ss_active {
    background-color: orange;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sShowGallery").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $(".sShow_bg").css("visibility", "visible");
    $(".sShow_bg a[href=#sld1]").addClass("ss_active");

    $("#sShow_nav").localScroll({
        target:'#sShowGallery', axis: 'x'
    });

    $(".sShow_bg a").click(function(){
        $(".sShow_bg a").removeClass("ss_active");
        $(this).addClass("ss_active");
    });
});
```

This will make your boxes one big user-friendly button. Unless you reply to the comment I left above, I'm assuming that you do *not* want to hide the paragraphs by default. That being said, there's no need to have two separate anchors for your action, as that confuses the user - who's probably used to clicking once in order to move a carousel.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and yeah that worked but not quite. I changed instead of `divs` to `ul li` for the `selectors`. But still can't get it right.